# Как изменить переменную JS в PHP в шаблоне странице WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

делаю свой шаблон страницы на вордпрес. Нужно чтоб основные картинки из подключенных категорий отображались списком, и при клике на одну из них, менялась картинка в другом блоке. Картинка должна соответствовать миниатюре, но быть размером "medium".
Проблема в том, что не как не могу понять, как заставить переменные различать эти картинки. Скрипт которые я написал, берет данные от первой картинки, и просто не обновляется, то есть можно сделать один клик и все выведенные картинки изменятся на первую и все. Как можно это реализовать

Пример последнего кода, который получился после все вариантов и поисков

```
                <?php
if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
  query_posts('cat=220');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
  while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога

    $imager3 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
                    $imager4 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'medium' );
                $imager5 =  get_the_ID();
                ?>
                  <img  src="<?php echo $imager4 ?>" id="<?php echo $imager5?>" onClick="chg2(<?php echo $imager5?>)"> 
                    
<?php
  endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
endif;
/* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
wp_reset_query();                
?>

<script>    
function chg2(){
    let idash = "<?php echo $imager5?>";
if (document.getElementById(idash).src="<?php echo $imager4?>"){
document.getElementById("per_4").src="<?php echo $imager3 ?>;"
}
}           
</script>
 <img src="1.jpg" id="per_4" style="width: 33%;">
```

Comment: Вы что-то перемудрили, по-моему. Во-первых, почему вы используете переменные, которые были в цикле, после того, как он закончился? А во-вторых, зачем значения этих же переменных вы вставляете в js скрипт?

Comment: Это уже просто безысходность и проверка всех вариантов. Было без них, но все равно не работало. 
Скрипт так же пробовал ставить в начало цикла
Было даже так - в onClick="chg2(this.id)"
И скрипт подвязан под айдишник - function chg2(id)

Comment: Если вы хотите таким образом делать, то вам в цикле в атрибуте `onclick` изображения нужно передать все необходимые параметры (`onclick="ch2('<?=image3?>')"`), а в скрипте их уже принять (`function chg2(link) {`). И внутри скрипта уже спокойно сделать подмену src (`document.getElementById("per_4").src=link;`). И никаких дополнительных условий не нужно

Comment: Не совсем понял
Это так надо? Но у меня что то не правильно
`code
$imager3 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
    ?>
      <img  src="<?php echo get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'medium' ) ?>" id="<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>" onClick="ch2('<?=imager3?>')"> 

 <img src="1.jpg" id="per_4" style="width: 33%;"> 
 <script> 
function chg2(link){
if (document.getElementById('<?php echo get_the_ID() ?>').src="<?php echo $imager4 ?>"){
document.getElementById("per_4").src=link;
 
}
}   
</script>`

Comment: Приложил код в ответе

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите таким образом делать, то вам в цикле в атрибуте onclick изображения нужно передать все необходимые параметры, а в скрипте их уже принять. И внутри скрипта уже спокойно сделать подмену src. И никаких дополнительных условий не нужно

```php
<?php
if ( have_posts() ) : // если имеются записи в блоге.
    query_posts('cat=220');   // указываем ID рубрик, которые необходимо вывести.
    while (have_posts()) : the_post();  // запускаем цикл обхода материалов блога

        $imager3 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'full' );
        $imager4 = get_the_post_thumbnail_url( get_the_ID(), 'medium' );
        $imager5 =  get_the_ID();
?>
        <img src="<?php echo $imager4 ?>" id="<?php echo $imager5?>" onClick="chg2('<?=$imager3?>')"> 

<?php
    endwhile;  // завершаем цикл.
endif;
/* Сбрасываем настройки цикла. Если ниже по коду будет идти еще один цикл, чтобы не было сбоя. */
wp_reset_query();
?>

<script>    
function chg2(link){
    document.getElementById("per_4").src = link;
}
</script>
<img src="1.jpg" id="per_4" style="width: 33%;">
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, все работает так как надо!